# What's the meaning of "He'll stay their wicked hand"

Tags: idioms

The song of [The Last Rose of Cintra](https://www.stlyrics.com/lyrics/thewitcher/thelastroseofcintra.htm) from the Netflix Witcher has the lines:

> So seek ye now the White Wolf
> He'll stay their wicked hand

What does it mean in the context of the song? I'm reading the meaning of the [idiom](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+someone%27s+hand) but still not sure.
Do they mean that the witcher (White Wolf) will not be affected by madness of the "time of axe and sword"?

Comment: *Answer in comment deleted.* If you know the answer, write an answer. If the question should be migrated, vote or flag for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Stay" is a synonym for "Stop" or "Halt" in this case. See defn 4a & 4b here:

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stay

```
4a: to stop or delay the proceeding or advance of by or as if by interposing an obstacle : HALT
4b: to check the course of (something, such as a disease)
```

"their wicked hand" most likely means "their wicked intentions".  To "stay someone's hand" means "to prevent them from doing what they were planning to do".

[https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+someone%27s+hand#:~:text=stay%20(one's)%20hand,him%20from%20his%20role%20instead](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+someone%27s+hand#:%7E:text=stay%20(one%27s)%20hand,him%20from%20his%20role%20instead).

Most commonly (I think), this is done by **persuasion rather than force**.  So you might stay someone's hand by saying "Wait, before you do that, have you thought about X?" for example.

Comment: He'll stop the bad guy from doing bad things.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily involve either physical force or persuasion: the OED suggests today it's most commonly used in legal contexts and of diseases, with other meanings a bit old-fashioned - as would befit Witcher - but certainly including the use of arms ("Attacking and withdrawing again before any force could be mobilized to stay him.")